# Ошибка при отправке HTTP-запроса с Android

Tags: android, kotlin

Хочу отправить HTTP-запрос с android (cyberforum взял как пример). Прочитал где-то, что подобное лучше делать через AsyncTask, но ничего не выходит.

Код:

```
package ssamvel.httpexes

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.net.HttpURLConnection
import java.net.URL
import java.nio.charset.Charset
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants.SECONDS
import android.os.AsyncTask
import ssamvel.httpexes.R.id.textView
import java.io.BufferedInputStream



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

fun hello(view: View) {
    val task = CatTask()
    task.execute()
}

internal inner class CatTask : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()

    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void): Void? {
        var urlConnection: HttpURLConnection
        var url = URL("http://www.cyberforum.ru")
        urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        var reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(urlConnection.inputStream))

        return null
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
    }
}

}
```

При асинхронном запуске вылезает ошибка:

> 3987-5800/ssamvel.httpexes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>       Process: ssamvel.httpexes, PID: 3987

При синхронном:

> 8253-8253/ssamvel.httpexes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: ssamvel.httpexes, PID: 8253
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:389)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
>        Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>           at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1303)
>           at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:86)
>           at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:74)
>           at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:752)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:187)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:156)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:98)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:345)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:328)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:246)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:457)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
>           at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
>           at ssamvel.httpexes.MainActivity.hello(MainActivity.kt:38)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:384) 
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Answer (score 3):

Вы делаете запрос в сеть из основного потока, что а андроиде давно запрещено. Вам надо открывать соединение с сетью в методе doInBackground:

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: HttpURLConnection): Void? {

    var urlConnection: HttpURLConnection
    var url = URL("http://www.cyberforum.ru")
    urlConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
    var reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(urlConnection.inputStream))

    return null
}
```

Comment: В hello() оставил только запуск task. Ошибка та же:
3253-3281/ssamvel.httpexes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: ssamvel.httpexes, PID: 3253

Comment: @ГошаОбыночный, если код у вас как сейчас в вопросе, то он не отличается от того, что был ранее. Потому и ошибка не меняется. Сделайте как у меня в ответе - перенесите код в метод класса AsyncTask

Comment: я так и сделал, перенес код в doInBackground

Comment: @ГошаОбыночный, обновите код в вопросе - покажите как именно у вас сейчас

Comment: ♦, поменял код.

Comment: @ГошаОбыночный, странно. Должно работать. Попробуйте тогда вместо устаревших AsyncTask + HttpURLConnection использовать OkHttp либу

Comment: ♦, ошибка найдена - запросы тупо не отправлялись с эмулятора. почему - не имею понятия, теперь приходится постоянно грузить APK на телефон